# Variable scope inside for and if/else

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, for-loop, scope

I have the following snippet of code which does not update the variable `CH_end` inside the `if else` statement unless I use 2 separate `if` statements.

```
for provider, games in content_providers.iteritems():

    if provider == 'Test':

        for state in states:        
            if state == states[-1]:
                CH_end =  '] \n}'
            else:
                CH_end =  '] \n},'


            if state == 'STATE1':
                print jsontemplate.CH_STATE1_start  

                for game in games:
                 if game == games[-1]:  
                    print game_data + '  }'
                 else:
                    print game_data + '  },'        

                print CH_end            


            if state == 'STATE2':
                print jsontemplate.CH_STATE1_start  

                for game in games:
                 if game == games[-1]:  
                    print game_data + '  }'     
                 else:
                    print game_data + '  },'    

                print CH_end

#more
```

If I change the second `if` block to the following it sort of works:

```
if state != states[-1]:
    CH_end =  '] \n},'
else:
    CH_end =  '] \n}'
```

with the above it executes the `if` but **never** sets the `CH_end` value in the `else` block.

Only way to get it work so far is by having 2 separate `if` blocks:

```
if state != states[-1]:
    CH_end =  '] \n},'

if state == states[-1]:
    CH_end =  '] \n}'
```

Granted I'm fairly new to Python, but I can't seem to make sense of this.

Comment: Are the duplicate `state == 'STATE1'` blocks intentional?

Comment: @chepner: ahh no, its updated now.

Comment: What's wrong with using `','.join(...)`?